# Data not displaying after axios call in React even though data exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, cloudinary

After making a `post` request with axios and getting the response back in a promise, the information exists but does not show up in the `preview`'s `.map()` loop. Unless I click on the page in the browser; then the images appear. It's as if the page renders before the data is available. I've tried `useEffect()` but the result is the same.

```
const [imageObjects, setImageObjects] = useState([])

const onDrop = useCallback(files => {
        const uploadUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_URL
        let _imageObjects = imageObjects.length > 0 ? imageObjects : []

        for (let file of files) {
            const fileName = file.name
            const uploadPreset = process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET
            let data = new FormData()
            data.append('upload_preset', uploadPreset)
            data.append('file', file)
            data.append('multiple', false)

            axios({
                url: uploadUrl,
                method: 'post',
                data,
                withCredentials: false,
                onUploadProgress: (e) => {
                    setProgress(Math.round((e.loaded * 100.0) / e.total))
                }
            }).then(res => {
                const delete_token = res.data.delete_token
                const secure_url = res.data.secure_url
                _imageObjects.push({ delete_token, secure_url })
                setProgress(0)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Error: ', err)
            })
        }
        setImageObjects(_imageObjects)

    })
```

The code for the `div` with a `preview` ID is here:

```
<div id="preview" style={{ border: '1px solid black', minHeight: "75", display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
     {imageObjects && imageObjects.map(img => {
          const delete_token = img.delete_token
          return (
                <span key={img.delete_token}>
                    <Link href="#" onClick={() => deletePhoto(delete_token)}>
                        <img src={img.secure_url} alt={img.secure_url} width="75" height="auto" />
                    </Link>
                 </span>
            )
      })}
 </div>
```

Unless I click anywhere in the browser, the images do not appear. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `setImageObjects` inside `then` callback and pass the newly formed array using the spread syntax to `setImageObjects`.

```
axios({
    url: uploadUrl,
    method: 'post',
    data,
    withCredentials: false,
    onUploadProgress: (e) => {
        setProgress(Math.round((e.loaded * 100.0) / e.total))
    }
}).then(res => {
    const delete_token = res.data.delete_token
    const secure_url = res.data.secure_url
    setImageObjects([...imageObjects,{
        delete_token,
        secure_url
    })
    setProgress(0)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err)
})
}
```